# Clearcase VOB merge

Tags: clearcase

How to merge the files bettween two different VOBS with different branches

Answer (score 1):

You can't through a regular ClearCase merge.

Merges are based on a [3-way merge between a common ancestor, a source and a destination version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771) of *the same file*

And by definition, files from different Vobs won't share a common history.

So the only way is a manual merge through a third-party external diff tool (like kdiff3 for instance), in order to compare/merge two different trees of files.
The fact that those trees are managed by ClearCase Vobs won't be relevant for that tool.